# Community Site users cache not refreshing

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder

Some time ago I updated a community site to remove an old visualforce page with an aura component that served a similar purpose. However, on occasion some users contact us having issues with the site and it is usually because they are still stuck on the old page until they refresh their cache by pressing Ctrl+F5.

The question is, is there something I can do on our end to make sure users who visited the site before the change are no longer directed to that old page and instead get to the new page?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Hard Reload with Cache Clear option.

### Ctrl + R (Reload)

When you press `Ctrl + R` in a web browser, you trigger a standard reload of the current webpage. This means that the browser will check if there are any changes to the webpage's content since it was last loaded. If there are changes, it will fetch the updated content from the server and display it. However, if the content hasn't changed, the browser might still use cached (stored) resources like images and scripts to load the page faster.

### Ctrl + Shift + R (Hard Reload with Cache Clear)

On the other hand, when you use `Ctrl + Shift + R` in a web browser, you initiate a hard reload with cache clearing. This is more thorough than a standard reload. It not only checks for changes on the server but also bypasses the cached resources stored locally on your computer. This ensures that you are seeing the most up-to-date version of the webpage, including all images, stylesheets, and scripts. It can be particularly useful when troubleshooting issues or when you suspect that cached content might be causing problems.

Comment: Hi Anton, I'm aware of how to locally update it, however for a customer who doesn't directly speak to us to be able to advise to refresh the page, I'm looking for a way to refresh it for everyone.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do it remotely in your case. However, if you have an access to the community, maybe you could add a help text somewhere that says how to refresh the page if people have issues?